# JavaScript navigation

Tags: javascript, html, css

Right so basicly what going on is I have a website I'm trying to build with a ajax navigation so it gets the webpages and loads them into the same page. what the issue is when I put content in normally it works fine but when I try to add content to an external doc and access it from the navigation the boxes split you can see it here http://101.177.243.251/

Does anyone know how to fix this. http://101.177.243.251/ is where it is hosted if you could have a look and see if you could help me.

Comment: **Post your code.** Links to live resources tend to change or break and when they do, it degrades the value of the question as a historical reference for those who may be experiencing a similar problem.

Comment: @esqew **PEBKAC** errors are pretty common...

Answer (score 2):

That gap is from the margin on the first paragraph tag.
The following CSS should fix the issue:

```
.pageContent {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```